# Style being cut off when it reaches 10000 characters

Tags: webpack, webpack-style-loader

I'm trying to load bootstrap css into my application using webpack. 
It's a large project and our bootstrap file was customized, so we can't load it from NPM anymore. We are trying to migrate it from gulp.

I'm importing it in my `main.sass` using @import.
`@import '../vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css';`

i'm using the following config in my webpack:

```
module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(s*)css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
            }
        ]
    }
```

When I check my HTML loaded in the browser my bootstrap.css file is there loaded inside a  tag, but strangely it ends at exactly 10,000 characters. So big part of BS css rules are cut off.

[image]

I couldn't find help on Google neither webpack, style-loader, css-loader documentation and issues.

Anyone has any ideia how to overcome this?

**setup:**

webpack 4.33.0

bootstrap 3.3.7

css-loader 2.1.1

style-loader 0.23.1

sass-loader 7.1.0

Answer (score 2):

I found out that the style is there but chrome doesn't show all the code. It only displays 10.000 characteres for some reason.

But if I copy the content os the style tag and throw it on VSCode all my CSS is there.

Also if a select the element on the console I can check that the length of characters is correct.

[image]